# VB.net | Save data from DataGridView to text file (Line per line)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, text-files

The application I designed so far has a DataGridView which loads data from a text file line per line.

All I want is for the code to save the (first row, first column) on the first line as a string, then (first row, second column) on the second line, etc.

Here is an example of what my table looks like:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|  ID  |  Date  |  Height  |  Weight  |  BMI  |  Units  |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|  01  | 16/06  |   1.74   |    64    | 20.9  | Metric  |
|  02  | 17/06  |   1.74   |    63    | 20.6  | Metric  |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

So from this example, after the data has been saved to the text file it should look exactly like this:

```
01
16/06
1.74
64
20.9
Metric
02
17/06
1.74
63
20.6
Metric
```

I came across some excellent code which does this with tabs, instead of a next line, here it is:

```
dgvMeasures.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText
dgvMeasures.SelectAll()
IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, dgvMeasures.GetClipboardContent.GetText.TrimEnd)
dgvMeasures.ClearSelection()
```

NOTE: The DataGridView is called dgvMeasures

Also please note that I cannot provide anything that I have already tried since there is nothing I can do, I have no idea what to do.

So if there is anyone who could help, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you just need to use a writer, and go through it in the way you want.

```
Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
    For row As Integer = 0 To dgvMeasures.RowCount - 1
        For col As Integer = 0 To dgvMeasures.ColumnCount - 1
            writer.WriteLine(dgvMeasures.Rows(row).Cells(col).Value.ToString)
        Next
    Next
End Using
```

This will go through each column for each row (as you describe), and then go to the next row.

I am sure you have a reason for writing the text file like this, but if you want to read it back in at some point, I would really recommend using a tab-delimited (or similar) format.

Comment: When I try and apply the changes to the table and it needs to save, it gives me this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred 
and
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: OKAY !!! Never mind I just removed the .ToString and it worked!
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @Ruan Oh! I guess ToString was giving you problems because some of the Values were Nothing. No problem :)

Comment: I realized that your code was also saving the last row which is always empty... So changing `.RowCount -1` to `.RowCount - 2` works